# How do today's solvers solve the closed solution of a system of equations

Tags: algorithms, closed-form

Both matlab's solve() function and Python's sympy library can solve the closed solution of equations. I want to know what algorithm they use. Is there a general way to solve the closed solution of equations? Or is the program only able to try to get a closed solution through experience?

for example, $solve(a^x = x,a)$ should be $a=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$, and it can be fairly complex when the number of equations is greater than 1.

I actually try to implement these algorithms, so I need to know how they work.

Some keywords or relevant papers is enough, thanks!

Comment: Apparently Newton method if one believes [this answer](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/298048-which-algorithm-does-vpasolve-use)

Comment: Only in exceptional cases , there is a "closed-form" solution , an exact value. Usually , the solutions can only be determined numerically.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by ‘through experience’?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which algorithms are implemented in the computer algebra systems.

An important part of the solution algorithms is algebraic simplification.

You could use the reporting commands of the software.

You could look in the computer algebra literature.

Polynomial equations can be solved in closed form with help of Galois theory.

For solving equations in closed form, one can use the following principle: The inverse relation of a function composition is the composition of the inverse relations of the members of the composition in opposite order.

Systems of polynomial equations can be solved in closed form by Buchberger's algorithm.

Buchberger's algorithm is a kind of Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm.

And then there are solution methods in terms of Special functions, e.g. Gamma function, hypergeometric functions or Lambert W.

Nowadays, deciding the solvability by [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) is probably not yet implemented. see e.g. [Chow 1999]